# magnific popup jquery style

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup, magnific-popup

I'm using magnific popup to load a php page but once the page opens, the selector in it doesn't pick up the jquerymobile style and only shows as a regular input selector.
I load the php page this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link href="../../jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- magnific popup -->
<link href="../../magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../magnific_popup.js"></script>

<script>
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme='a'>    
         $.magnificPopup.open({
                closeOnContentClick:false,
                closeOnBgClick:false,
                    items: {
                        src: '../../test-ajax.php
                  },
                  type: 'ajax'  }, 0);
                  }
```

In the test-ajax.php page I have:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head>
<body><div id="custom-content" class="mfp-bg style="max-width:100%; margin: 20px 
auto;">
    <style>
    #custom-content img {max-width: 70%;margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

    <select name="test" id="test" onChange="ReadForm (this, false);">
                                <option value="a">yadayada</option>
                                <option value="b">yadayada</option>
</select>
</body></html>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

from jQM docs

> If you manipulate a select via JavaScript, you must call the refresh
>   method on it to update the visual styling. Here is an example:

```
var myselect = $("select#test");
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

or trigger this on the element that needs to be processed by JQM. JQM processes all elements once document is ready, ie. when the page loads, you are initiating this popup after this, so you have to tell jQM explicitly to process this code.

The refresh should be done after magnificpopup inserts the code into DOM, check for any callbacks provided by them. I havent used magnificpopup myself.

Also check [jQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) and make sure you follow their guidelines on how to use `select` jQM way.

Comment: Tried your suggestion in magnificpopup callback to no avail.

open: function() {
    var myselect = $("select#test");
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
  },